# Sending AdWords conversion data to a different account via GTM?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I have control over a client's site, and can access and edit code. A third party controls the client's Google AdWords account and has no access to their site's code. Is it possible for me to implement a conversion tracking code through GTM, and send that data back to the third party's AdWords account?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you'll need to:

- Create a Google Tag Manager Container.
- Add the Container code to the site, just after the opening  tag.
- Insert the Adwords Tag (as in the screenshot below).
- Publish the Container.

[image: New Adwords Tag]